# CASE WHEN expressions in django and casting in aggregate functions

Tags: python, django, casting, conditional-operator, case-when

When I'm trying to do sth like this:

```
data = [Table.objects.filter(nr=form.cleaned_data['id']).aggregate(
                avg = Avg(Case(When(Q(floatColumn__lt=250)&Q(floatColumn__gt=-250))))]
```

The error appears:

> function avg(text) does not exist

Could I do sth like manual casting in sql ?

```
ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN residual<250 THEN residual else null end)::numeric,2)
```

Hope you will help me ! Thanks in advance